# In der Zukunft oder in die Zukunft?

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context, standard-german

Ich habe einen Satz gelesen, in dem "in die Zukunft" benutzt worden ist. Ich wollte wissen, warum nicht "in der Zukunft"?

> ... geht es darum, kreativ neue Wege in die Zukunft zu erschließen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Antwort auf Deutsch

Sowohl *in die Zukunft* als auch *in der Zukunft* sind grammatisch korrekt, sie bedeuten nur etwas verschiedenes.

In *in die Zukunft* steht *Zukunft* im Akkusativ, sodass eine *Richtung* angezeigt wird. In *in der Zukunft* steht *Zukunft* im Dativ, sodass ein *Ort*  angezeigt wird.

Der Unterschied wird bei einer Übersetzung ins Englische deutlich, weil das Englische die Unterscheidung von Dativ und Akkusativ nicht kennt und daher verschieden Präpositionen verwendet. Die beiden Wortgruppen lassen sich wie folgt ins Englische übersetzen:

*Wege in die Zukunft* hieße auf englisch: *Ways into the future*.

*Wege in der Zukunft* hieße auf englisch: *Ways in the future*.

Daran sieht man, dass *Wege in der Zukunft* im gegebenen Zusammenhang keinen Sinn ergibt.

### Answer in English

Both *in die Zukunft* and *in der Zukunft* are grammatically correct, they just mean something different.

In *in die Zukunft*, *Zukunft* is in accusative case, thus a direction is indicated. In *in der Zukunft*, *Zukunft* is in dative case, thus a location is indicated.

So, these are the translations of the two phrases:

*Wege in die Zukunft* translates to *Ways into the future*.

*Wege in der Zukunft* translates to *Ways in the future*.

From that you can see, that *Wege in der Zukunft* does not make sense in the given context.

Comment: Eigentlich sollte man ja auf auf Deutsch gestellte Fragen auch auf Deutsch antworten, aber an der englischen Übersetzung sieht man in diesem Fall sehr gut, wo der Unterschied liegt.

Comment: Oh, das war ein Versehen. Ich füge noch die Deutsche Antwort hinzu

Answer (score 6):

Sowohl "in die Zukunft" als auch "in der Zukunft" sind korrekte Ausdrücke, aber haben eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung:

- **"in" + Akkusativ: Angabe der Richtung**
- **"in" + Dativ: Angabe des Ortes**

Ein physischeres Beispiel:

> Ich bin in die Stadt gefahren.

= Ich bin von außerhalb in die Stadt hinein gefahren.

> Ich bin in der Stadt gefahren.

= Ich war von Anfang an in der Stadt und bin dort herumgefahren.

In deinem Beispielsatz ist ein Weg in **Richtung** Zukunft gemeint, nicht der **"Ort"** Zukunft, daher wurde "in die Zukunft" geschrieben.

Answer (score 3):

"In die Zukunft" ist etwas, das jetzt beginnt und in die Zukunft hineinreicht (oder führt), während "in der Zukunft" noch nicht begonnen hat.
"Wege in die Zukunft" sind also Wege, die in der Vergangenheit begonnen haben oder jetzt beginnen, und in die Zukunft hineinfinden.
Wege in der Zukunft sind noch nicht vorhanden, werden es aber eines Tages (in der Zukunft) sein.

Comment: "Ich werde morgen anfangen, Wege in die Zukunft zu erschließen." - hat auch noch nicht begonnen.

Comment: @Annatar: Wird aber morgen beginnen.